# Can I create sandboxed gem environments in rbenv?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I want to install two Ruby gem applications `foo` and `bar`. They both require the same version of Ruby (2.4.1). How can I use rbenv to install them independently, so that their dependencies do not interfere?

For example:

1. Create environment 1 (Ruby 2.4.1)
2. `gem install foo`
3. Create environment 2 (also Ruby 2.4.1, but distinct)
4. `gem install bar`
5. `rbenv rehash`
6. Run either `foo` or `bar`
7. Update `foo`, gems in environment 1 are updated, gems in environment 2 are not updated

How do I perform steps 1 and 3?

Comment: related link https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/1113

Comment: The simplest way is just to use `bundler`. Don't rely on globally installed gems (`gem install foo`), but instead put all dependencies in a `Gemfile`.

Comment: The existence of `bundler` is largely why many people advocate using `rbenv` over `rvm` in the first place.

Comment: @TomLord I've come across bundler, but it seems to be more for managing a environment associated with a source-based project, I'm looking for "just" environment/package management, closer to `apt`

Comment: In that case, use `rvm` with a `gemset`, instead of `rbenv`.

Comment: However, I would question why you need to manage the ruby environment so carefully *without a project*... It's a valid thing to do, but unusual. 9 times out of 10, when someone tells me they need this, it's actually because they're trying to run code that didn't define its dependencies properly; which is precisely what `bundler` solves.

Comment: thanks! related link: https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics

Comment: Rbenv is a pretty simple tool, and it has no functionality to work with different gemsets under box. However there is a plugin for that functionality, so you can look there: https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset

Comment: @Medvedu please expand on that as an answer and I will accept it, thanks!

Comment: a brief definition of a "gemset" would help ruby newbies like me :) I can see now I was assuming that an "environment" was both a "ruby environment" and a "gemset"